# Is there way I can fix the ios toolchain?

Tags: macos, flutter

I have fixed the brew doctor and installed the python. Now I have this problem which i can't get rid of. I followed the steps and the problem still was not solved

```
Zuhairs-MacBook-Pro:~ zuhairhallak$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel dev, v1.4.14, on Mac OS X 10.14.4 18E226, locale en-US)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[!] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.2)
    ✗ Verify that all connected devices have been paired with this computer in
      Xcode.
      If all devices have been paired, libimobiledevice and ideviceinstaller may
      require updating.
      To update with Brew, run:
        brew update
        brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies libimobiledevice
        brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies usbmuxd
        brew install --HEAD usbmuxd
        brew unlink usbmuxd
        brew link usbmuxd
        brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
        brew install ideviceinstaller
[!] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.33.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

Comment: Why did you tag this with [Flutter]?

Comment: Because Im getting another error in flutter. The only way to solve flutter error is to brew link python.

Comment: I see. Flutter does use brew to update some components, so the underlying problem may stem from the same place. But the phrasing of your question has absolutely nothing flutter about it. I might suggest swapping out the tag for python as the are like a kagillion more python devs than flutter...

Comment: I have fixed that problem but now I have different problem.

Comment: This is a very different question than the original, so will be signing off after this, but doctor is giving you hints above. If you are trying to build iOS for an actual device, eg not an emulator you'll need to register a dev account with Apple (free) to even install it. You'll also have to trust your dev account from the device settings too. These questions have definitely already been answered here on SO. Parting words of wisdom, keep your IDEs up to date, type flutter upgrade whenever is says updates to flutter, definitely get the Android studio dart plug in, even if your VS. Best!

Comment: I solved my question. I have found many questions have the same issue as my problem but my problem was never solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is how I solved this error.


Zuhairs-MacBook-Pro:~ zuhairhallak$ brew install --HEAD libplist
    Error: libplist 2.0.0_1 is already installed
    To install HEAD_1, first run `brew unlink libplist`.
    Warning: Skipping (old) /usr/local/Cellar/libplist/2.0.0_1 due to it being linked
    Zuhairs-MacBook-Pro:~ zuhairhallak$ brew link pkg-config
    Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.29.2
    To relink: brew unlink pkg-config && brew link pkg-config
    Zuhairs-MacBook-Pro:~ zuhairhallak$ brew unlink pkg-config && brew link pkg-config
    Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.29.2... 4 symlinks removed
    Linking /usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.29.2... 4 symlinks created
    Zuhairs-MacBook-Pro:~ zuhairhallak$ flutter doctor
    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
    [✓] Flutter (Channel dev, v1.4.14, on Mac OS X 10.14.4 18E226, locale en-US)

    [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    [✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.2)
    [!] Android Studio (version 3.3)
        ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
        ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    [✓] VS Code (version 1.33.1)
    [!] Connected device
        ! No devices available

    ! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```